# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}$ through Riemann sum

Tags: integration, limits, summation

I am stuck in this problem: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}$$
While it can be easily solved using partial fractions, I wanted to solve this through Riemann sums which I terribly failed at. The results were different. Here's my procedure. Please tell me where I've gone wrong.

**Partial Fraction Method**
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i+1}-\frac{1}{i+2} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Reimann Sum Method**
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}$$
$\text{Let }x=\dfrac{i}{n} \implies dx=\dfrac{1}{n} \text{. Therefore the above expression reduces to:}$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{(nx+1)(nx+2)}}$$
$\text{Supposing } t=\dfrac{nx+2}{nx+1} \text{, reduces the above expression to:}$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_2^{\bigl(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\bigr)}{\frac{(nx+1)^2dt}{-n(nx+1)(nx+2)}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\bigl(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\bigr)}^2{\frac{dt}{t}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\Biggl(\ln2-\ln{\biggl(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\biggr)}\Biggr)=\ln2$$

Comment: As you get the wrong answer in your second method, then it is clearly flawed. The first method is sound and simple.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Even though the first method is correct, I'm curious as to why the second method is failing.

Comment: What is the definition of the Riemann integral, and why does that *reduce* the original expression into the specified integral?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL It's a simple substitution, I've stated it in my question.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma: there are several errors. First off, $\lim f g = \lim f \lim g$ when $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ exist. In your case, this is not true. Second off, $n$ is the number of partitions in the discrete Riemann integral, but it also appears in the limiting Riemann integral (it probably should not).

Comment: You've got an $n$ inside your integral!

Comment: What happens exactly at the point after "Therefore the above expression reduces to..."? Do we replace a sum by an **equal** expression? (It is hard to understand "$dx=1/n$".)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I also had a hunch about it. But I still am unable to understand it.

Comment: @dan_fulea I've substituted $r=nx$ and turned the summation to integral since x varies from 0 to 1 in a highly dense manner(that is, it occupies each rational value between 0 and 1)

Comment: Again the question, do we replace a sum by an **equal** expression? (If yes, then i will compute the values for $n=1$, a rational number against some logarithm of... and we easily find the error...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have stated $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{(nx+1)(nx+2)}} $ you are using this: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f\cdot g=\lim_{n\to \infty}f\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}g$$ As, while converting the the sum into integral you are taking limit. But, to hold this property both of the limits need to be hold. Here, $\lim_{n\to \infty}n$ does't exists.